# Problems with Qt in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, vlc, qt

I've been trying to install quassel via `apt` and get the following error:

```
quassel: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5DBus.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

VLC also has a very similar problem:

```
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[0000562e813679d8] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000562e8147ec68] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0000562e8147ec68] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0000562e8147ec68] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

I've done my best to install the missing libraries, but it just doesn't seem to resolve the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Performing `locate libQt5DBus` yields:

```
/home/tom/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-41.4.80/libQt5DBus.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.prl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5.9
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5.9.1
```

Comment: I guess you mean 17.10?

Comment: my bad, typo. Fixed.

Comment: For the first issue, try `sudo apt install libqt5dbus5`. Maybe that hels VLC as well.

Comment: Apparently, it's already the newest version

Comment: What does `sudo updatedb ; locate libQt5Dbus.so.5` say then?

Comment: I'll add the output to the question as an edit.

Comment: Ah, no need. It's not there. It produces no output.

Comment: Then try `sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5dbus5`, seems like that file got deleted somehow then...

Comment: Ok done, still not present. Still getting the same errors.

Comment: This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 btw, as of today. So I haven't messed the conf up in some other way.

Comment: It needs to be libQt5DBus, not libQt5Dbus in the command.

Comment: Will add as an edit to the question

Comment: Try `sudo ldconfig`, then run `quassel` again.

Comment: @emk2203 that doesn't solve the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: What output do you get with `ldconfig -p | grep libQt5DBus`

Comment: libQt5DBus.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 _(line break)_
 libQt5DBus.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so

Comment: Did you install Qt using apt? Could you provide the output of `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libQt5DBus`.

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 root root      1105 Sep 23  2017 libQt5DBus.prl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        19 Sep 23  2017 libQt5DBus.so -> libQt5DBus.so.5.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        19 Sep 23  2017 libQt5DBus.so.5 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root        19 Sep 23  2017 libQt5DBus.so.5.9 -> libQt5DBus.so.5.9.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    562584 Sep 23  2017 libQt5DBus.so.5.9.1